# Unable to start jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I am unable to start jboss 7.1.1 server on the server,

I have set both JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_home.

for some reason it stops after

'if errorlevel 1 ( "" -XX:+TieredCompilation -version 1>nul 2>&1 if not errorlevel 1 (set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=stand alone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval= 3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml" ) ) )}'

***Below is the log generated***

> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>if "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final" NEQ
>   "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1. Final" (echo WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to
>   a different installation - un predictable results may occur. )
>
> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>set DIRNAME=
>
> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" (set
>   "PROGNAME=stand alone.bat" )  else (set "PROGNAME=standalone.bat" )
>
> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>rem Setup JBoss specific properties
>
> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>set
>   JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M
>   -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi. dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolv er.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.def ault.config=standalone.xml
>
> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>if "xC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18;
>   E:\Program F iles\Java\jdk1.6.0_18;" == "x" ( set  JAVA=java  echo
>   JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.  echo Set
>   JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message. )
>
> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>if not "" == "true" ( rem Add -client to
>   the JVM options, if supported (32 bit VM), and not overriden
>
> echo "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun .rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djav a.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
>   -Djboss.modules.sys tem.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"   | fin dstr /I -server  1>nul  if errorlevel 1 ( "" -client -version   2>&1  | findstr /I
>   /C:"Client VM"  1>nul
>
> if not errorlevel 1 (set "JAVA_OPTS=-client
>   -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms6 4M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.r mi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -Dorg.jboss.res olver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server. default.config=standalone.xml" ) )
>
> rem Add compressed oops, if supported (64 bit VM), and not overriden
>
> echo "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun .rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djav a.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
>   -Djboss.modules.sys tem.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"   | fin dstr /I "-XX:-UseCompressedOops -client"  1>nul
>
> if errorlevel 1 ( "" -XX:+UseCompressedOops -version  1>nul 2>&1
>
> if not errorlevel 1 (set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+UseCompressedOops
>   -Dprogram.name=stand alone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval= 3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman
>   -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml" ) )
>
> rem Add tiered compilation, if supported (64 bit VM), and not
>   overriden  echo "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun .rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djav a.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
>   -Djboss.modules.sys tem.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"   | fin dstr /I "-XX:-TieredCompilation -client"  1>nul
>
> if errorlevel 1 ( "" -XX:+TieredCompilation -version  1>nul 2>&1  if
>   not errorlevel 1 (set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+TieredCompilation
>   -Dprogram.name=stand alone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval= 3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman
>   -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml" ) ) )}

Comment: can someone look into this problem?

Comment: could you provide some information about the issue? what is your operating system, java runtime, java version, java configurations, how did you try to start jboss, is it vanilla jboss or have you changed something... have you tried re-installing?

Comment: I belive the configuration process is case sensitive, therefore you can try to set JBOSS_HOME not JBOSS_home.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with folder path containing spaces (or quotes), I guess. 
Either JBOSS_HOME or JAVA_OPTS .

==> Work-around: Install JBoss on a folder whose path does not contain spaces, parenthesis, quotes, Unicode characters.

Example of JBoss home:

- C:\Program Files\jb-eap-6         --> Bad (spaces)
- C:\Program Files (x86)\jb-eap-6   --> Worse (spaces & parenthesis)
- C:\jb-eap-6                       ==> OK , no spaces no parentheses.
- D:\apps\jb-eap-6                  ==> OK , no spaces no Unicode

If the problem still remains, apply that work-around for JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTS as well.

P/S: Don't ask me why JBoss scripts suck on Windows !